# Android Studio, does it use SDK Tools?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently developing in Eclipse and have upgraded to the latest 4.4W platform, SDK Tools 23.0 and the latest Eclipse plugin. It seems that each release for the Eclipse IDE gets worse and worse, to the point now where Proguard is missing and it's looking for an annotations.jar that doesn't exist. I can't manage to do a previously working Ant release proguarded build from the command line either.

If I migrate to Android Studio, will it still use the same folders as Eclipse and therefore exhibit the same problems that I currently have regarding Proguard and the annotations.jar?

Comment: Not sure if you're the one who filed [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72444), but if not, you might keep an eye on it with regards to the missing-ProGuard problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I've starred this one https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419 which is a duplicate that predates 72444

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  Yes, it uses SDK tools. Android Studio, which is based on IntelliJ, can either adapt to Eclipse class, properties files and project structure (which I assume is what you mean by "same folders as Eclipse"), but you configure this easily.

I'd reccommend migrating to IntelliJ. It is (supposedly) cross-compatible with Android Studio, but without the bugs of an IDE (e.g., Android Studio) that is essentially in its Beta stage.
(If you don't know, Android Studio is based off of IntelliJ).

If you're not overly attached to Ant, you can perform a Gradle export in Eclipse, and import easliy into IntelliJ. I just made the switch myself.

The Android-Gradle plugin comes with built-in Proguard support as shown [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard)

Comment: What does the Android-Gradle plugin plug into? Is it Eclipse or IntelliJ or Android Studio? I am attached to Ant for release builds and to Eclipse for day to day stuff. I don't want to migrate, but if they are going to keep turning out crap like this latest 'upgrade', I may have no other option.

Comment: Android-Gradle is a plug-in for Gradle, which is the build solution that Google is pushing right now. I wouldn't expect things to get better on the Eclipse ADT side, as Google is probably going to focus on Android Studio (and IntelliJ by association). That said, IntelliJ/AS has an Eclipse compatibility mode, and Ant and Gradle are not incompatible.